# Plot learning curves with caret package and R

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I would like to study the optimal tradeoff between bias/variance for model tuning. I'm using caret for R which allows me to plot the performance metric (AUC, accuracy...) against the hyperparameters of the model (mtry, lambda, etc.) and automatically chooses the max. This typically returns a good model, but if I want to dig further and choose a different bias/variance tradeoff I need a learning curve, not a performance curve.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say my model is a random forest, which has just one hyperparameter 'mtry'

I would like to plot the learning curves of both training and test sets. Something like this:

[image: learning curve]

(red curve is the test set)

On the y axis I put an error metric (number of misclassified examples or something like that); on the x axis 'mtry' or alternatively the training set size.

Questions:

1. Has caret the functionality to iteratively train models based of training set folds different in size? If I have to code by hand, how can I do that?
2. If I want to put the hyperparameter on the x axis, I need all the models trained by caret::train, not just the final model (the one with maximum performance got after CV). Are these "discarded" model still available after train?

Comment: See: http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#plotting-the-resampling-profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, probably after this question was asked, the caret package added the `learning_curve_dat` function which helps assess model performance across a range of training set sizes.

Here is the example from the function documentation:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1412)
class_dat <- twoClassSim(1000)

set.seed(29510)
lda_data <- learning_curve_dat(dat = class_dat, 
                               outcome = "Class",
                               test_prop = 1/4, 
                               ## `train` arguments:
                               method = "lda", 
                               metric = "ROC",
                               trControl = trainControl(classProbs = TRUE, 
                                                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary))

ggplot(lda_data, aes(x = Training_Size, y = ROC, color = Data)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = loess, span = .8)
```

The performance metric(s) are found for each Training_Size and saved in lda_data along with the Data variable ("Resampling", "Training", and optionally "Testing").

Here is a link to the function documentation: https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/learning_curve_dat.html

To be clear, this answers the first part of the question but not the second part.

**NOTE** Before at least August 2020 there was a typo in the caret package code and documentation.  The function call was `learing_curve_dat` before it was corrected to `learning_curve_dat`.  I've updated my answer to reflect this change.  Make sure you are using a recent version of the caret package.

Comment: I was scratching my head why this function doesn't work and I've noticed that there's a typo in the caret package, it's spelled as `learing_curve_dat()`, instead of `learning_curve_dat()`.

Comment: Good spot!  I've updated my answer.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The spelling mistake has now been fixed.

Comment: @SimonWoodward Thanks for update on learing_curve_dat spelling fix.

Answer (score 4):

1. Caret will iteratively test lots of cv models for you if you set the
   `trainControl()` function and the parameters (e.g. mtry) using a `tuneGrid()`.
   Both of these are then passed as control options to the `train()`
   function. The specifics of the tuneGrid parameters (e.g. mtry, ntree) will be different for each
   model type.
2. Yes the final `trainFit` model will contain the error rate (however you specified it) for all folds of your CV.

So you could specify e.g. a 10-fold CV times a grid with 10 values of mtry -which would be 100 iterations. You might want to go get a cup of tea or possibly lunch.

If this sounds complicated ... [there is a very good example here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process) - caret being one of the best documented packages about.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, but I'm still in doubt. What I need is *not* to iteratively train on different folds for CV (boostrap,...), but simulate the entire train() process (including CV and so) with different subsets of the training set (10%, 20%...100%). I, basically, would like to aestimate if more training set size would reduce my high variance. For 2., I need the error rate of varying the hyperparameter mtry, but if I understood what you mean, trainFit will have the error rate calculated on different CV folds (while the final one is the average of all, I suppose)

Comment: If you want to make pre-train splits then use `createDataPartition` to make several different balanced trainSets e.g train10,train20,train100, then run `train` with a matrix of `tuneGrid` options on each. You may even have to repeat with a few different draws train10a, train10b,train10c etc.

Comment: As far as I can read, with tuneGrid I can specify the range of every hyperparameter to be tested. This is great. Then, I will use createDataPartition to pre-split the data and call train() n times using a loop (or something like that). So, just need to solve the last question: how to get error rate of varying parameter?

Comment: @StephenHenderson That link is ded. I believe this is what you are referring to [the Caret package documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process) by Max Kuhn

Comment: @EkabaBisong Thanks I've edited the original answer to use the new link you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my code on how I approached this issue of plotting a learning curve in `R` while using the `Caret` package to train your model. I use the `Motor Trend Car Road Tests` in R for illustrative purposes. To begin, I randomize and split the `mtcars` dataset into training and test sets. 21 records for training and 13 records for the test set. The response feature is `mpg` in this example.

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(7)

# randomize mtcars
mtcars <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars)),]

# split iris data into training and test sets
mtcarsIndex <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = .625, list = F)
mtcarsTrain <- mtcars[mtcarsIndex,]
mtcarsTest <- mtcars[-mtcarsIndex,]

# create empty data frame 
learnCurve <- data.frame(m = integer(21),
                     trainRMSE = integer(21),
                     cvRMSE = integer(21))

# test data response feature
testY <- mtcarsTest$mpg

# Run algorithms using 10-fold cross validation with 3 repeats
trainControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
metric <- "RMSE"

# loop over training examples
for (i in 3:21) {
    learnCurve$m[i] <- i
    
    # train learning algorithm with size i
    fit.lm <- train(mpg~., data=mtcarsTrain[1:i,], method="lm", metric=metric,
             preProc=c("center", "scale"), trControl=trainControl)        
    learnCurve$trainRMSE[i] <- fit.lm$results$RMSE
    
    # use trained parameters to predict on test data
    prediction <- predict(fit.lm, newdata = mtcarsTest[,-1])
    rmse <- postResample(prediction, testY)
    learnCurve$cvRMSE[i] <- rmse[1]
}

pdf("LinearRegressionLearningCurve.pdf", width = 7, height = 7, pointsize=12)

# plot learning curves of training set size vs. error measure
# for training set and test set
plot(log(learnCurve$trainRMSE),type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Training set size",
          ylab = "Error (RMSE)", main = "Linear Model Learning Curve")
lines(log(learnCurve$cvRMSE), type = "o", col = "blue")
legend('topright', c("Train error", "Test error"), lty = c(1,1), lwd = c(2.5, 2.5),
       col = c("red", "blue"))

dev.off()
```

The output plot is as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!!　This is exactly what I was looking for.