# How to plot a learning curve in R?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I want to plot a learning curve in my application.

A sample curve image is shown below.

[image]

Learning curve is a plot between the following Variance,

- X-Axis: Number of samples (Training set size).
- Y-axis: Error(RSS/J(theta)/cost function )

It helps in observing whether our model is having the high bias or high variance problem.

Is there any package in R which can help in getting this plot?

Comment: Hi, please kindly show appreciation by upvoting and clicking the green arrow to pick an answer that was useful in any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make such a plot using the excellent [Caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package. The section on [Customizing the tuning process](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process) will be very helpful.

Also, you can check out the well written blog posts on R-Bloggers by Joseph Rickert. They are titled ["Why Big Data? Learning Curves"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/why-big-data-learning-curves/) and ["Learning from Learning Curves"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-from-learning-curves/).

**UPDATE**
I just did a post on this question [Plot learning curves with caret package and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370827/plot-learning-curves-with-caret-package-and-r/40885119#40885119). I think my answer will be more useful to you. For convenience sake, I have reproduced the same answer here on plotting a learning curve with R. However, I used the popular `caret` package to train my model and get the RMSE error for the training and test set.

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(7)

# randomize mtcars
mtcars <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars)),]

# split iris data into training and test sets
mtcarsIndex <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = .625, list = F)
mtcarsTrain <- mtcars[mtcarsIndex,]
mtcarsTest <- mtcars[-mtcarsIndex,]

# create empty data frame 
learnCurve <- data.frame(m = integer(21),
                     trainRMSE = integer(21),
                     cvRMSE = integer(21))

# test data response feature
testY <- mtcarsTest$mpg

# Run algorithms using 10-fold cross validation with 3 repeats
trainControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
metric <- "RMSE"

# loop over training examples
for (i in 3:21) {
    learnCurve$m[i] <- i

    # train learning algorithm with size i
    fit.lm <- train(mpg~., data=mtcarsTrain[1:i,], method="lm", metric=metric,
             preProc=c("center", "scale"), trControl=trainControl)        
    learnCurve$trainRMSE[i] <- fit.lm$results$RMSE

    # use trained parameters to predict on test data
    prediction <- predict(fit.lm, newdata = mtcarsTest[,-1])
    rmse <- postResample(prediction, testY)
    learnCurve$cvRMSE[i] <- rmse[1]
}

pdf("LinearRegressionLearningCurve.pdf", width = 7, height = 7, pointsize=12)

# plot learning curves of training set size vs. error measure
# for training set and test set
plot(log(learnCurve$trainRMSE),type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Training set size",
          ylab = "Error (RMSE)", main = "Linear Model Learning Curve")
lines(log(learnCurve$cvRMSE), type = "o", col = "blue")
legend('topright', c("Train error", "Test error"), lty = c(1,1), lwd = c(2.5, 2.5),
       col = c("red", "blue"))

dev.off()
```

The output plot is as shown below:
[image: MtCarsLearningCurve.png]